# Firebase rewrites not working on hosted site

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've been trying to get Firebase rewrites working on my Firebase hosted site. And it won't work no matter what I try. Right now I have my rewrites all routed to a routing function called app.
As you can see below >>

### firebase.json

```
     {
            "public": "public/dist-main",
            "target": "public-store-easy",
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "/**",
                    "function": "app"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Here is my function for routing >>

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const html = require('html')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('/../public/'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/dist-main/index.html', { root: '../public' })
})
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/dist-main/login.html', { root: '../public' })
})
app.get('/HOME', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/dist-main/home.html', { root: '../public' })
})
app.get('/feedback', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/dist-main/feedback-form.html', { root: '../public' })
})
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I expected it to work just fine because it worked just fine in my localhost server and on the firebase serve, server.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: What is actually happening when you try to access the site? Do you get any error messages when you try to deploy? We don't have enough information here to help you debug.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh get a 404 error 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deployed Cloud Functions only have access to files that are within the `functions` directory. You are trying to send files from `../public` which is not deployed with functions.

If you want this to work, you'll need to move the `public` directory inside the `functions` directory and update the `{"hosting": {"public": ""}}` key appropriately.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! It works perfectly now.